# How to avoid greedy or non-specific regex?

Tags: java, regex

***//---------EDITS MADE FOR CLARITY--------//***

I've looked over the rest of the web but so far no answers have satisfied my question. I've got a regex that is being a bit too greedy for what I'm trying to do. For example, the following regex:

```
(?<piece>q|k|b|p|n|r+)(?<color>l|d)(?<x>\\w)(?<y>\\d)
```

will match

```
rdh8

rda6

rla1 a3

rlb2
```

However, **I need my regex to be specific; I need it to exclude "rla1 a3".**
Currently, the regex matches the 'rla1' portion of the `rla1 a3`. I need the regex to completely disregard 'rla1 a3' because of the ' a3'.

I have attempted solutions such as `\s?$` but these have not worked. Any ideas whats wrong?

****EDIT****
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

Here is some sample code of the problem.

```
public ArrayList<String> theStringsToBeRead = new ArrayList<String>();

public void addLines() throws IOException
{
    String line;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testFile"));

    //put each line into an arraylist
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        theStringsToBeRead.add(line.toLowerCase()); //adds each line to the arraylist
    }
    //parse each line in arraylist
    for(String item : theStringsToBeRead)
    {
        testing(item); //for each line, run a regex check
    }
}

public void testing(String item)
{

    String regex = "(?<piece>q|k|b|p|n|r+)(?<color>l|d)(?<x>\\w)(?<y>\\d)";
    //String StevesRegex = "^(?<piece>q|k|b|p|n|r+)(?<color>l|d)(?<x>\\w)(?<y>\\d)$";  //doesnt appear to work
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(item);

    while (m.find()) 
    {
        System.out.println(m.group("piece")+m.group("color")+m.group("x")+m.group("y"));
    }   
}
```

The text file is:

```
rdh8
rda6
rla1 a3
rlb2
```

The output I get is:

```
rdh8
rda6
rla1
rlb2
```

The desired result is that the regex completely ignores all of "rla1 a3" instead of matching a portion of it. The desired output would then be:

```
rdh8
rda6
rlb2
```

Any help would be appreciated, very sorry to have confused anybody as to the question. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You're a bit unclear.  Are you only trying to match one entry per line?  If there are more, then you don't want to match?

Comment: What should be the input and output? Its still unclear

Comment: sorry, check the edit. That is more clear.

Comment: Is the `*` part of the text or are you trying to italicize it?  Please remove all hilighting metacharacters and use code formatting (indent 4 spaces) for things that need to be literals.

Comment: "rdh8" and "rla1 a3" are two separate strings I want to match. However, the goal is to create a regex that matches the first, but excludes the second.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "will match". That regexp should give one match for both strings. Add `^` and `$` to match entire string only.

Comment: I already answered this question.  Not sure why you're continuing to make edits.  Is my answer unclear?

Comment: `^\\s*(?<piece>[qkbpnr])(?<color>[ld])(?<x>\\w)(?<y>\\d)\\s*$]` maybe.

Comment: you can use do while loop to get first string and exclude others

Comment: Yes, if the goal is to have a regex that matches only a string that matches this pattern from beginning to end, and not when there are miscellaneous other characters in the string, add `^` at the beginning of the regex and `$` at the end, as Steve said.

Comment: tried this solution and it didn't work :(
It just matches the "rla1" portion of the "rla1 a3" item. I need the regex to reject the entire item if it has spaces/letters/numbers trailing the "rla1".

Comment: @user2453973 That could not have possibly worked on that input, since there is a `^` at the beginning and a `$` at the end...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but if you just want to match at the beginning of the input, then the following would suffice:

```
String regex = "^(?<piece>q|k|b|p|n|r+)(?<color>l|d)(?<x>\\w)(?<y>\\d)$";
```

`^` says "at the start of the line"
`$` says "end of the line"

Here's a [link](http://rextester.com/EXUJ9190) to test it online.

**EDIT**:
Your issue is due to whitespace, to remove whitespace before or after the string, use `.trim()`, ie:

```
String s = br.readLine().trim().toLowerCase();
```

Alternatively, you could change the regex to account for whitespace as follows:

```
String regex = "^\\s*(?<piece>q|k|b|p|n|r+)(?<color>l|d)(?<x>\\w)(?<y>\\d)\\s*$";
```

Comment: I need the regex to match the first item but exclude the second.

Comment: It would, but if I have a list of either strings, its only going to match the first string. Furthermore, if I were to make "rla1 a3" the first item in the list, this regex would still match it. I need to have the regex exclude any item with additional letters/numbers behind it

Comment: if i had a list of 

    blc1, rla1 a3, nlb1, blc1     

my goal would be to have the regex match only the last two and first one. Your regex only matches the very first item in the list. If i were to make "rla1 a3" the first in the list, it would match the "rla1" portion. I need the regex to completely reject a match on "rla1 a3" because of the trailing "a3".

Comment: My requirements, one last time, correct me if they don't make sense: I need the regex to reject any item that has trailing spaces/letters/numbers. --- for example, "rla2" would be a match, while "rla2 a4" is entirely rejected as a match because of the " a4". ----- does that make sense?

Comment: see my edit of that comment, i neglected to insert comments. each item  should be on its own seperate line. It should look like:
    blc1 
    rla1 a3 
    nlb1 
    blc1

Comment: each item (blc1), (rla1 a3), (nlb1), and (blc1) should all be on seperate lines but the commenting here doesnt allow me to do so.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the commenting method does not allow me to give the items the correct format.

Comment: unfortunately no, my regex matcher will match the "rla1" portion of "rla1 a3". i need the regex to reject the entire item (rla1 a3) because of the trailing ( a3).

Comment: no i definitely am not, according to regex.powertoy.org (this is the regex tester i am using) your regex only matches the very first item... for example, if i insert "rla1 a3" as the first item, it will match the "rla1" portion of that item, which I need it not to do.

Comment: Sorry mate, your regex doesn't match any of the items. I tested it both in the regex tester and in my program and it couldn't match a single item.

Comment: I do not see the link, but i made edits to the question and posted sample code of what i am doing currently. If you could review it, I think it would probably clear up some of our miscommunication in previous discussions.

Comment: I ran your code and your regex works in your example code. I am confused, because in my sample code that I provide, using your regex doesn't work at all. Run my sample code that I just edited in. My output continues to be the undesired result if i use your regex. It really does not work, I have no idea why this is occuring.

Comment: @user2453973 I was hoping that this wasn't the case.  Sorry, you weren't trolling.  The issue is that there's most likely a newline or some sort of whitespace at the end of each string (or at the beginning of the string).  Use the `.trim()` command on the strings.  This will remove whitespace before and after the string.

Comment: @user2453973 I made an edit which explicitly shows how to do the above.  It will work.  Please re-accept my answer when it does. :)

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks for all your patience and help, so sorry for being confusing and dragging you through all this considering that the issue was whitespace issues... ugh thats just frustrating on so many levels. Thanks Steve! Have a good one.

Comment: @user2453973 Now I feel bad.  I'm really sorry--thought you were screwing with me.  Have a good one, man.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though this part of your regex matches *rdh8*:

```
(?<piece>q|k|b|p|n|r+)(?<color>l|d)(?<x>\\w)(?<y>\\d)
```

and this is the part that matches *rla1 a3*:

```
\s+(.*?)
```

If you want your regex only to match the first expression it finds and stop matching there, try removing the `\s+(.*?)` from the end of the regex.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to remove that piece on my regex. The edited regex is the one that is causing me trouble. "\s+(.*?)" was a previous attempt that did not work.

Comment: in short, removing \s+(.*?) has no effect, the rest of the regex still matches a portion of both items. I need the regex to match the first item but exclude the second.